# MySQL - Use On Update Cascade to activate Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

How to use `On Update Cascade` to activate a `Trigger`in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SoYuJe, you don't use 'on update cascade' to activate trigger.
You will write the trigger and make it listen the event which is update in this manner. standart trigger templates would help you easily, since there is also no info about tables i think thats all i can say.

Comment: So I guess `On Update Cascade` cannot activate a `Trigger` in MySQL? Is it?

Comment: no, on update cascade is also waiting to be triggered to do its job. its job is not to call a trigger but rather to do the necessary update. So the answer is, no, but the closest workaround might be as i said, write a trigger that listens for update and if you will do integrity check on the trigger, you can remove on update cascade.